# std::hash template partial specialization

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, std, language-lawyer

I wrote some class with template:

```
 template <class T, class Allocator = ::std::allocator<T> >
 class my_list;
```

I should write ::std::hash specializtion for this class. How can I do that?
Simple partial specialization:

```
namespace std {
  template <class T, class Allocator>
      class hash<my_list<T, Allocator> >{
      public :
      size_t operator()(const my_list<T, Allocator> &x ) const{
          return ...;
      }
  };
}
```

But I can't write simple partial specialization, because it forbidden by C++ ISO:

> ISO/IEC 14882 Third edition 2011-09-01
>
> 17.6.4.2.1 Namespace std [namespace.std]
>
> 2 The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it declares ... an explicit or partial specialization of any member class template of a standard library class or class template.

What can I do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The paragraph you're quoting does not apply. You're partialy specialising a *class template* (`std::hash`), not a ***member class template** of a standard library class or class template.* `std::hash` is not a member of any class or class template.

For your case, paragraph 1 of the same section applies, and that allows specialisation when at least one user-defined type is involved (emphasis mine):

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace `std` or to a
>   namespace within namespace std unless otherwise specified. **A program may add a template specialization
>   for any standard library template to namespace `std` only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type**
>   and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly
>   prohibited.

Comment: I remember that C++ user can't define partial specialization for "::std::swap(T<A,B>&, T<A,B>&)". He should define new swap function at namespace with class "template <class A, class B> class T;". I thought this is same situation.

Comment: @user3098730 `std::swap` is a *function* template, not a *class* template. Function templates cannot be partially specialised at all; this follows from the rules of the language and has nothing to do with `std`.